# Matsu-Tribe Decoy vs. Trap Runner

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I activate [Matsu-Tribe Decoy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMatsu-Tribe%20Decoy%5d)'s ability targeting opponent's [Trap Runner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTrap%20Runner%5d), can he activate Trap Runner's ability, blocking my creature, and making Trap Runner an illegal target for Matsu-Tribe Decoy's ability?

https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=75247
https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=22288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For this particular combination of cards, there is no time during which the Matsu-Tribe Decoy is a legal target for Trap Runner's ability.

The Oracle text for Trap Runner's ability says:

> Target unblocked attacking creature becomes blocked. Activate this ability only during combat after blockers are declared.

Since this ability can only be activated after blockers are declared, Trap Runner would first have to block the Decoy... but then the Decoy is no longer an **unblocked** attacking creature.

---

Note also that your question asks about making the Trap Runner an "illegal target" for the Decoy's ability. Nothing about the Decoy's target being tapped (or otherwise unable to block) would make it an *illegal* target... just not one worth spending the mana on.

Comment: Why can this ability only be used after blockers are declared?  Edit: NM, found the relevant rule; 509.1h governs when an attacker becomes a unblocked attacker, so before blockers are declared there is no legal targets.

Comment: While you are correct, and there is no such thing as an "unblocked" attacker before blockers have been declared, note also that Trap Runner explicitly specifies this window in its oracle text, so it would be true even if 509.1h didn't exist.